# Callback method for Zoom In/Zoom Out video in AVPlayerViewController in tvOS

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

[image: Shared Image of Tap to Zoom Video option]

I am trying to find the method from where I can detect whenever user zoom in/out video in tvOS by enabling **Tap-to-Zoom Video -> On**.

Please help me!!!